# How to Clean Sticky Residue on My Smartphone?

Tags: nexus-4

I had this my Nexus 4 for over 3 years and have upgraded to newer smartphone. I wish however to still keep my Nexus 4. I kept it in Diztronic TPU protective case that worn out with time and no longer has that tight fit feel to it. It has accumulated some little sticky residue on its sides and it attracts lint and dust:
[image]
[image]

I have no idea how to clean it to get rid of sticky residue and everything else that it managed to attract. I tried rubbing alcohol but it was a short term solution and soon I was back where I started. The sides are not made of some smooth material. It's a hard silicone and due to friction it makes it harder to clean. Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Kinda off-topic (more related to the physics of the device instead of Android), but I'll chime in and give my advice anyway.

Comment: The fake rubber material around the edges is wearing off, you can "clean" it all you want but the material is just breaking down... you are better off to just clean it good and get another case, or replace the back panel.

Answer (score 2):

Former N4 owner here.

I sanded off all those stuff with a fine sandpaper, which made the sides slick. Also, the white version of the back cover assembly doesn't come with this faux-skin material, so I bought one and swap it in (just 2 screws away) when I feel like it.

Comment: So this dust and particles appear with no relation to what case you used for N4?

Comment: It's the faux-skin material itself showing its age. Mine is very carefully protected, and far not as worn as yours, but still.